# Path with rounded corners in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am trying to use Inkscape to draw a path consisting of line segments, where the corners are rounded, like the bold black arrows in this image. I tried the Bezier tool, but couldn't achieve the desired effect. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/640954

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Inkscape (Version 0.92), select the Bezier Tool and put it in BSpline Path mode

[image: BSpline Path Mode]

Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> as you use the tool. This will help you constrain the paths to straight horizontal/vertical/diagonal lines.

This is where you need to place your nodes. You need three nodes like this for each corner.

[image: Node placement example]

The Bezier tool will make the curves you need automatically when in BSpline Path mode.

Examples

[image: Examples]

Update June 2020: Since Inkscape 1.0 has now been released, curved corners are available as a path effect called **Corners (Fillet/Chamfer)**

Comment: If you want to have rounded ends of strokes too, press `shift + ctrl + f` (Fill and stroke) and set that in tab `Stroke style`.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the 'pinch' on the inner corner with bspline?  Pinch can be seen on most 90deg corners in your diagram.

Comment: @EoghanM - you can make the corners less tight by spacing out the nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this post - it seems there is some functionality in the development release that may help - path...path effects...fillet/chamfer.

https://superuser.com/questions/640954/inkscape-rounding-corners-of-shapes

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! The best answer for my version 1.0 (4035a4f, 2020-05-01). They added this feature.